# Can't obtain user's currently playing track, GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing 400

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, spotify

I am trying to learn how to use the Spotify API to experiment and hopefully make a full project with. I was able to obtain the access token from user login. However, I am not sure how I am supposed to make a fetch request to obtain the user's currently playing track data. This is my code so far:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';
import {Container, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const CLIENT_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID;
const CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_SECRET;
const REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:3000'
const AUTH_ENDPOINT = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize'
const RESPONSE_TYPE = 'token'

const scopes = ['user-read-currently-playing'];

function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState('')
  const [currentTrack, setCurrentTrack] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const hash = window.location.hash
    let token = window.localStorage.getItem("token")


    if (!token && hash) {
        token = hash.substring(1).split("&").find(elem => elem.startsWith("access_token")).split("=")[1]

        window.location.hash = ""
        window.localStorage.setItem("token", token)
    }

    setToken(token)
    currentlyPlaying()
  }, [token])

  const logout = () => {
    setToken('')
    window.localStorage.removeItem('token')
  }

  async function currentlyPlaying(){
    var params = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
      }
    }

    var currentPlay = await fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing', params)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {setCurrentTrack(data)})
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container className='d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center' style={{minHeight:'100vh'}}>
          {!token ?
          <Button 
            href={`${AUTH_ENDPOINT}?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}&response_type=${RESPONSE_TYPE}&scope=${scopes}`} 
            className='btn btn-success'>Login</Button>
          : <Button 
            onClick={logout}
            className='btn btn-danger'>Logout</Button>}

      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Whenever I am redirected back after the login, I get these errors in the console

```
App.js:54     GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing 400
currentlyPlaying @ App.js:54
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
VM766:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at App.js:54:1
    at async currentlyPlaying (App.js:54:1)
```

I am not sure what is wrong, some help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add a .catch(error => console.log(error)) to the end of your fetch request. It's currently responding with a status 400 which is a bad request and an uncaught exception. This way you can catch it and it might respond with additional details in the console.

Comment: ok I have added that and now I am getting network response was not okay, what does that mean? I am also getting unexpected end of JSON input, basically the same errors

Comment: That would be an issue with the fetch statement. Try adding the parameters into the fetch statement itself rather than externally. I.E:
`var currentPlay = await fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing", {
      method: "GET",

      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
      })      
.then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {setCurrentTrack(data);})
   .catch(error => console.log(error));`

I don't think it will help though, the syntax looks fine to me.

Comment: also try adding `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` to your headers. It could help.

Comment: @B-Brazier this is a GET request that doesn't have any body, so specifying a `Content-Type` is pretty pointless. And their examples are not sending any header but Authorization either, https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-the-users-currently-playing-track

Comment: Thanks, but I ended up opting to use a node library I found called 'spotify-web-api-js' that wraps all requests into functions, and it works. I still don't understand where I went wrong because I feel like I followed the documentation correctly.